# jquery autoload not working with multiple field having same class

Tags: jquery

html code

```
                   <div class="multi-field-wrapper panel-body">
                                <div class="multi-fields " >
                                    <div class="multi-field row form-group">
                                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                                            <input type="text" name="box_no[]"  placeholder="Box No" class="form-control" required>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <input type="text" name="product_name[]"  placeholder="Product Name" class="auto form-control" required>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="mb-md hidden-lg hidden-xl"></div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                                            <input type="text" name="product_quantity[]" id="product_quantity" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control" required>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="mb-md hidden-lg hidden-xl"></div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                                            <input type="text" name="price[]"  placeholder="Price" class="form-control" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-md hidden-lg hidden-xl"></div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                                            <button class="remove-field btn-success" type="button"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>    
                                 <button type="button" class="add-field btn-primary">Add More Product</button>
                                </div>
```

javascript for autoload

```
    $(function(){
        $(".auto").each(function(){ 
            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: "<?=BASE_ADMIN_URL?>invoice/getAutoCompliteData" ,
            });
        });
    });
```

i am adding row dynamically with this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
        var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);

        $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
            $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input:text').val('').focus();
        });

        $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
            if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
                $(this).parent().parent('.multi-field').remove();
        });
    });

});
```

Problem is autoload works fine with first element of class
[image]

But when i add another element autoload shows result only on first element

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're adding `.auto` to the new element?

Comment: yes i use clone function.it also call autocomplete function but it shows suggestion on first text box

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your autoload/autocomplete function again.  Because it happens immediately on page load, it isn't affecting anything you add to the page after the fact.  Try calling that function when you create the new input.

Comment: tried that but same problem.it's  calling autocomplete function from new text box but it shows suggestion on first text box

Comment: Try `$(".auto").each(function(input){  input.autocomplete({`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize plugins for HTML elements which *don't exist yet*.  jQuery only works on elements in the present, it can't reach into the future.

Any time you add a new element and want to initialize a plugin for it, you have to initialize that plugin.  Perhaps something like this:

```
$(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
    var newElement = $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input:text');
    newElement.autocomplete({
        source: "<?=BASE_ADMIN_URL?>invoice/getAutoCompliteData" ,
    });
    newElement.val('').focus();
});
```

Comment: when i remove $(".auto").each(function(){ 
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
     source: "<?=BASE_ADMIN_URL?>invoice/getAutoCompliteData" ,
    });
   }); this code and call autocomplete on new element its working perfectly on new element .but both dose not working together

Comment: and its also show autocomplete on all 4 new input field

Answer (score 0):

Here,  "multi-field-wrapper" is a parent class that is not repeating and "auto" is a class of the fields under repeating area where you want to initialize the autocomplete. Its working perfect for me.

```
$(".multi-field-wrapper").on('focus',".auto",function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({
            source: "<?=BASE_ADMIN_URL?>invoice/getAutoCompliteData" ,
    });
});
```